# Yii recognise timestamp column

Tags: yii

I'm using giix to extend model (and crud) behavior. In this I would like to handle columns of type timestamp (that already exist in my model) specifically, rather like autoincrement fields are handled. (Ignored and not shown, that is.) However, there is no property `$column->isTimestamp`. I would like to add this somewhere, but I'm rather at loss what the best place for this would be. Do I put it in giix somewhere, or do I have to extend the column-baseclass?

Edit: I want to ignore them from every view, for every table. Since this is a lot of work, and it's something I always want, I'd like to automate it. Adapting the generators seems to make most sense, but I'm not sure what the best way to do it would be.

Comment: I dont exactly unterstand what you are trying to do? you want to extend giix for your own code generation ignoring timestamps? or where do you want to ignore them? why not just remove them from the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the process:

1. Extend your database schema, if you are on MySQL it is CMysqlSchema.
2. Extend CMysqlColumnSchema and add a "isTimestamp" attribute.
3. In your CMysqlSchema sub-class extend createColumn and test for a timestamp, you'll see that Yii makes simple string comparisons here to set it's own flags. Set "isTimestamp" in your CMysqlColumnSchema here.
4. Tell Yii to use your schema driver like this in your components section in the config:

> ```
> 'db' => array(
>   'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database',
>   'username' => '',
>   'password' => '',
>   'driverMap' => array('mysql' => 'CustomMysqlSchema'),
> ),
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to query the column schema, I've not used giix but find where it is generating the views, it should be looping through either the model attributes or the underlying table schema.

If it is looping through the schema:

```
//you can also ask Yii for the table schema with Yii::app()->db->schema->getTable[$tableName];
if ('timestamp' === $tableSchema->columns[$columnName]->dbType)
  continue; //skip this loop iteration
```

If it loops over the attributes:

```
$dbType = Yii::app()->db->schema->getTable[$model->tableName]->columns[$modelAttribute]->dbType;
if ('timestamp' === $dbType)
  continue; //skip this loop iteration
```

Comment: Well, it's more to centralize the comparison (I get nervous about string comparisons, and just hope 'type' doesn't suddenly get changed to upper case or something.) But thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you're concerned about case, just call strtolower.

Comment: I know, but I'd like to centralize such a check, rather than code it in different places. Usually good coding practice.